# Why the actual hazard ratio of the simulated time-to-event data is very different from the expected value?

Tags: survival, simulation, cox-model, exponential-distribution, hazard

I am trying to generate time-to-event data for two treatments, with 25 patients in each arm. I generated the survival time in the treatment arm using an exponential distribution with parameter 0.95, and in the control arm using parameter 1.0. I assumed that all patients would experience an event without censoring. The expected hazard ratio between the two treatments is 0.95.

After generating the simulated data, I used Cox regression to estimate the actual hazard ratio between the two treatments. However, the estimated hazard ratio was 0.59, which is very different from the expected hazard ratio.

What could be the reason for such a large discrepancy between the expected and actual hazard ratios in the simulated data?

Here is the code I tried

```
set.seed(123)
#assign treatment indicator
treatment = rep(c(0, 1), each = 25)

#generate survival time
time_control = rexp(25, rate = 1)
time_new = rexp(25, rate = 0.95)
time = c(time_control, time_new)

#assume all patients have events without censoring
event= rep(1, 50)
data <- data.frame(treatment = treatment, time = time, event = event)

#estimated hazard ratio by cox regression
library(survival)
coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ treatment, data)
#> Call:
#> coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ treatment, data = data)

#>           coef exp(coef) se(coef)    z    p
#> treatment -0.52      0.59     0.29 -1.8 0.07
```

Comment: Increase the number of simulated subjects. Does the behaviour persist?

Comment: Also, try different random seeds. Your model results are well within what might be expected from random sampling.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same random seed but replace `25` with `2500` and `50` with `5000` for the numbers, then you get the expected coefficient and hazard ratio:

```
coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ treatment, data)
# Call:
# coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ treatment, data = data)
# 
#               coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z      p
# treatment -0.05108   0.95021  0.02830 -1.805 0.0711
# 
# Likelihood ratio test=3.26  on 1 df, p=0.07115
# n= 5000, number of events= 5000
```

The hazard ratio you specified is very close to 1. Even with 5000 events, this larger random sample doesn't find a "statistically significant" difference under the usual *p* < 0.05 criterion.

The result from the sample of 50 that you took was well within sampling error. As a quick check, take 999 random samples of 25 treatment and 25 control cases from these 5000. Look at the distribution of coefficient estimates.

```
set.seed(20230316)
c999 <- double(999)
for(sample in 1:999) {
      cSample <- data[sample(1:2500, 25, replace=TRUE),];
      tSample <- data[sample(2501:5000, 25, replace=TRUE),];
      c999[sample] <- coef(coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ treatment, data = rbind(cSample,tSample)))
      }
```

95% of the coefficient estimates are between

```
c999[order(c999)][25]
# [1] -0.6704489
c999[order(c999)][975]
# [1] 0.5502292
```

Your particular value is well within those limits.

```
ecdf(c999)(-0.52)
#[1] 0.05505506
```

With your small sample size of 50, there was an even smaller coefficient estimate in more than 5% of samples from these 5000.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!  So randome sampling is the reason, I understand it now.